# ArcGIS Pro not seeing all records from attribute table located on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, arcgis

I created a table to test ArcGIS Pro 2.2.3 with an Azure SQL Server. The structure of the table is simply an OBJECTID, a shape (Point) and a text field. The table contains a set of 2 points with different locations.

I am then loading this table as a Feature Class into a map in ArcGIS Pro. I can see the 2 points and I can select them both from the map view. The issue I have is that **the Attribute Table only lists a single point when listing all records**. Furthermore I get the following behaviour from the Attribute Table:

- If looking at **all records** with **nothing** selected on map: I see **1 record** and caption says "**0 of 1 selected**"
- If looking at **selected records** with **nothing** selected on map: I see **no record** and caption says "**0 of 1 selected**"
- If looking at **all records** with **both** selected on map: I see **1 record** and caption says "**2 of 1 selected**" (*see image below*)
- If looking at **selected records** with **both** selected on map: I see **2 records** and caption says "**2 of 1 selected**"

[image: Example with 2 points selected on map and only 1 shown in Attribute Table]

The table itself was not created by ArcGIS Pro but was defined in SQL as a table with a spatial field using the following code. The database is hosted on an Azure SQL Server:

```
/****** Object:  Table [geotest].[geometry] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [geotest].[geometry](
    [OBJECTID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Shape] [geometry] NULL,
    [col_as_text] [nchar](100) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_geometry] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [OBJECTID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO

/****** Object:  Index [FDO_Shape] ******/
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [FDO_Shape] ON [geotest].[geometry]
(
    [Shape]
)USING  GEOMETRY_AUTO_GRID 
WITH (BOUNDING_BOX =(-400, -90, 400, 90), 
CELLS_PER_OBJECT = 16, PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
GO
```

Comment: Please note that I also posted this question on GIS stackexchange a while ago but since it did not get much attention I tought it might be more dev related. If anyone feels it is against stackexchange rules I will remove the GIS version: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298365/arcgis-pro-missing-records-in-attribute-table-from-sql-server

Comment: I think this question has a better chance of being answered at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange where I have just placed a bounty to try and draw more attention to it.